# Kurento hello world doesn't showed video

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am new in kurento. I have installed kurento 6.0 in my PC having ubuntu 14.04 (using the [following](https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/installation_guide.html) procedure) and tried to run the hello world example. After installation,
1- I run kurento with:

`sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start`

To clone and launch the hello-world java version using:

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
mvn compile exec:java
```

3- Access to the webpage
https:localhost:8443

But when I click on start no video has been displayed {captured from my laptop camera}; the loading image is always displayed. Note that the same issue is observed on both chrome and firefox.

The following is the console log displayed by the web page

```
Page loaded ...
Starting video call ...
Creating WebRtcPeer and generating local sdp offer ...
```

What I am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is any error coming on the console where the server is started?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem. The problem was that the brower_component/adapt.js/adapter.js was found by the navigator.This file is useful for using browser methods like userMedia... So I have downloaded the adapter.js script from the web and placed it into the previous path.

Now the file is found and the hello world is working as espected